# Count grouped colums and group them via other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem.
The data:

```
2016-11-09  0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E
2016-11-09  866D70EC-93FD-4C30-BC54-C7B954F255BE
2016-11-09  6C090D6B-9842-4CB0-9E10-F9B941C8D3A1
2016-11-09  FB1DD63E-F098-4191-B8F4-BEA4F9776B54
2016-11-09  FB1DD63E-F098-4191-B8F4-BEA4F9776B54
2016-11-10  0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E
2016-11-10  NULL
2016-11-10  0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E
2016-11-11  0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E
2016-11-11  0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E
```

From it I want to count UserId and group via Date.
I should be like this:

```
Date | Unique | Returning | New
..09  | 4      | 1         | 3
..10  | 2      | 1         | 1
..11  | 1      | 1         | 0
```

How I can do it? 
I have this query.

```
select 
    cast(EventTime as date) as 'Date', 
    count(distinct UserId) + count(distinct case when UserId is null then 1 end) as 'Unique users',
    0 as 'Returning users',
    0 as 'New users'
from 
    TelemetryData 
where 
    DiscountId = '5F8851DD-DF77-46DC-885E-46ECA93F021C' and EventName = 'DiscountClick'
group by 
    cast(EventTime as date)`
```

Unique users = unique with NULL too!

Returing users = UserId who clicked more than 1 times `isnull(sum(case when UserId(here shoudld be count) > 1 then 1 else 0 end), 1)`

New users who clicked only one! `isnull(sum(case when UserId(count also) = 1 then 1 else 0 end), 1)`

@EDIT:
Ok, two of your results work perfect. But I need now integrate it with other query.

`SELECT
            '5F8851DD-DF77-46DC-885E-46ECA93F021C',
            cast([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventTime] as date) as 'Date', 
            sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountLike' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Likes',
            sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountDislike' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Dis likes',
            sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountSharing' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Shares',
            SUM(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountView' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Views',
            SUM(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountClick' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Clicks', 
            Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCode' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Downloaded codes',
            Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountSave' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Saves',
            sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClickWWW' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Page redirections',
            Round(
                cast(Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountClick' then 1 else 0 end) as float) 
                / 
                cast(
                    case when SUM(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountView' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 1
                    else SUM(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountView' then 1 else 0 end) end as float)
                * 100, 2)
            as 'Average CTR',
            0 as 'Unique users',
            0 as 'New users',
            0 as 'Returning users',
            Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentPositive' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Positive comments',
            sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentNegative' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Negative comments'
        from [dbo].[TelemetryData] 
        where [dbo].[TelemetryData].[DiscountId] = '5F8851DD-DF77-46DC-885E-46ECA93F021C'
            and ([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountView' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClick' or 
            [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountDislike' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCode' or 
            [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountLike' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountSharing' or
            [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClickWWW' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountSave' or
            [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentPositive' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentNegative')
        group by cast([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventTime] as date)
        order by cast([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventTime] as date) asc`

Now it will be hard...

Comment: Your sample data has two columns (which ones?), but your query references at least 3 columns.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Data has more columns but I need olny operate on these two. Data and UserId.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want aggregated user information in your results. One obvious and simple solution is to group by date and user first so as to get this information per user and date and only later group by date only.

```
select 
  eventdate,
  count(*) as unique_users,
  count(case when cnt > 1 then 1 end) as returning_users,
  count(case when cnt = 1 then 1 end) as new_users
from
(
  select cast(eventtime as date) as eventdate, userid, count(*) as cnt
  from telemetrydata
  where ...
  group by cast(eventtime as date), userid
) date_user
group by eventdate;
```

Comment: Not working. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'unique'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
Incorrect syntax near 'date_user'.

Comment: Okay. That teaches us: don't use reserved words for columns, tables, and aliases :-) As this is SQL Server use `[unique]`. (In a more standard compliant DBMS you'd use `"unique"` instead). Or use another name like `unique_users`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be i don't understand you question but looking to your data seems that you need

```
select 
     date
   , count(*) as unique
   , (count(*) - count(distinct user_id))  as returning
   ,  count(distinct user_id) as new

group by date 
were user_id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select Date, uniques, returning, uniques-returning as new
from (    
    select Date, 
           sum(case when row_num = 1 then 1 else 0 end) uniques, 
           sum(case when row_num = 2 then 1 else 0 end) returning
    from(    
        select cast(EventTime as date) as Date, 
               ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by EventTime, userid order by EventTime) row_num
        from TelemetryData) cte1    
    group by Date)cte2
```

Hope this should help you

Comment: Error: Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 51
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'cte2'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a Common Table Expression:

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #TelemetryData
(
   EventTime  Date,
   UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
   )


INSERT INTO #TelemetryData
VALUES
('2016-11-09', '0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E'),
('2016-11-09', '866D70EC-93FD-4C30-BC54-C7B954F255BE'),
('2016-11-09', '6C090D6B-9842-4CB0-9E10-F9B941C8D3A1'),
('2016-11-09', 'FB1DD63E-F098-4191-B8F4-BEA4F9776B54'),
('2016-11-09', 'FB1DD63E-F098-4191-B8F4-BEA4F9776B54'),
('2016-11-10', '0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E'),
('2016-11-10',  NULL),
('2016-11-10', '0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E'),
('2016-11-11', '0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E'),
('2016-11-11', '0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT EventTime, 
           UserId, 
           COUNT(*) cnt, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventTime ORDER BY EventTime) RN
    FROM #TelemetryData
    GROUP BY EventTime, UserId
)

SELECT EventTime, 
       MAX(RN) AS [Unique],
       SUM(CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as New, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Returning
FROM CTE
GROUP BY EventTime
```

**Results**

```
EventTime   Unique  New Returning
2016-11-09  4       1   3
2016-11-10  2       1   1
2016-11-11  1       1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work:

```
select EventTime,
    max(DistinctRank) [Unique],
    sum(CountOfDistinct - 1) Returning,
    max(DistinctRank) - sum(CountOfDistinct - 1) New
from
    (select distinct EventTime,
        UserId,
        rank() over (partition by EventTime order by UserId) DistinctRank,
        count(1) over (partition by EventTime, UserId) CountOfDistinct
    from TelemetryData) sub
group by EventTime
```

The subquery (run it separately and see for yourself) will return the unique combinations of EventTime and UserID, along with the the rank of each unique UserId for a given date, and the count of distinct values for each combination of EventTime and UserId:

```
EventDate               UserId                               DistinctRank  CountOfDistinct
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000 0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E    1             1
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000 6C090D6B-9842-4CB0-9E10-F9B941C8D3A1    2             1
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000 866D70EC-93FD-4C30-BC54-C7B954F255BE    3             1
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000 FB1DD63E-F098-4191-B8F4-BEA4F9776B54    4             2
2016-11-10 00:00:00.000 NULL                                    1             1
2016-11-10 00:00:00.000 0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E    2             2
2016-11-11 00:00:00.000 0536B088-D3DE-4C0E-903F-C2463D0AAB7E    1             2
```

Then the outer query gets the maximum DistinctRank for each unique pair, which is the number of unique UserIds for the EventDate, and essentially the sum of the subquery records where there were duplicates in UserId for a given EventDate, which is the number of returning users. The New column is just the difference between Unique and Returning. The result is:

```
Event Date                Unique  Returning  New
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000   4       1          3
2016-11-10 00:00:00.000   2       1          1
2016-11-11 00:00:00.000   1       1          0
```